# getting database toArray not work in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

when I get data from database like

```
$agent = DetailUser::get();
```

It's getting well.
But when I return

```
$agent = DetailUser::get()->toArray();
```

It say not found and error 404.
why this happen ?

here is my migration

```
        Schema::create('detail_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id_detail_user');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_user');
        $table->string('nama');
        $table->string('institusi');
        $table->bigInteger('telepon');
        $table->bigInteger('saldo')->default(0);
        $table->string('foto')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('id_user')->references('id_user')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

here is my model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DetailUser extends Model
{
protected $primaryKey='id_detail_user';
protected $table = 'detail_user';
protected $fillable = ['nama','institusi','foto','telepon','saldo'];
protected $appends = ['image_URL'];

public function getImageURLAttribute()
{
    if ($this->foto == null) {
        abort(404);
    }
    return asset('uploads/peserta/' . $this->foto);
}
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'id_user');
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share your route and controller?

Comment: Mine is working fine. The problem is not here, on your mentioned code

Comment: Mine too. I don't think it is related to the query.

Comment: i already update the model and migration, my controller just like the first code try to get data from db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are serializing that Collection to an array which is causing the accessor, `getImageURLAttribute`, to be called for every model; you have this appended to the serialized output. So apparently one of those doesn't have a `foto`.

You are literally aborting with a 404 in that method.

Comment: what should i do to replace abort (404) when user has no foto ?

Comment: how about nothing, or use some default image